# SQL Server - view Nodes elements in Xquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x='<data>
<add key="images" value="image/path/img.gif">a</add>
<add key="images2" value="image/path/img2.gif" >b</add>
<add key="images3" value="image/path/img3.gif" >c</add>
</data>';


SELECT  s.value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)')  AS myVal from @x.nodes('/data/add') AS   t(s)
```

I want to see (3 add's elements)

```
add
add
add
```

but all I see is

```
a
b
c
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use local-name() instead:

```
SELECT  s.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(8000)')  AS myVal 
from @x.nodes('/data/add') AS t(s)
```

Refer to Microsoft's XQuery Reference for more info:  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)

Comment: Where can i find all this internal Commands ? Ive been trying whole day.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: how about [MSDN docs: XQuery Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)

Comment: @NathanSkerl thanks. Can you please tell me why will I ever want to use .query ? I cant find any scenarios...

Comment: @RoyiNamir .value() returns a scalar value while .query() returns a subset of the xml you are querying as xml doc.

Comment: @NathanSkerl I know that scalar returns one. my question is when will i ever need to use query alone ?  can I shred a particilar section from .query result ?  can you please post sample ? :)

Comment: ok, simple example using your data would be to find the first 'add' element using query, then use value to get the element:   select @x.query('/data/add[1]').value('.', 'varchar')